# New column in Pandas DataFrame based on whether any value from a list appears in the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I am trying to add a new column to my dataframe based on whether a list of values appears or not in the dataframe. Here a toy example:

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [22, 45, 68],'b' : [11, 23, 89], 'c' : [17, 49, 56]})

    a   b   c
0   22  11  17
1   45  23  49
2   68  89  56
```

and a list of values:

```
a=[17,21,12,89,77,99]
```

I would like to add a column based on whether any value from my list of values "a" appears on the dataset. In order to do that I can do the following:

```
train["is_in_a"] = (train["a"].isin(a) | train["b"].isin(a) | train["c"].isin(a)).astype("int")

    a   b   c   is_in_a
0   22  11  17     1
1   45  23  49     0
2   68  89  56     1
```

This is OK for a small dataset. However I would like to do this for a dataset with thousands of columns, so I cannot write this statement for such a big case. Is there a way of writing the same but in a more efficient and tidy way? Thanks!!

Comment: I think its a dupe, use train.isin(a).any(1).astype(int)

Answer (score 1):

I believe a simple `apply` would do

```
train.apply(lambda k: any(x in a for x in k), axis = 1)
```

Or

```
train.isin(a).apply(any, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Both solutions are way more elegant than mine :)